# Kendo NumericTextBox Percent Sign

Tags: razor, kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

I am Trying to add the percent sign to the grid. I have found some posts which using this workaround. But this does not work.

"# \%" --> causes a javascript error

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m => m)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
    .Format("\\# \\%")
)
```

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution in the telerik forum (http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-show-a-percentage-dollar-symbol)

```
 columns.Bound(e => e.ContractPercent).ClientTemplate("\\#=kendo.format(\"{0:p}\", ContractPercent / 100)\\#").EditorTemplateName("NumberPercent");
```

regards

Answer (score 1):

Format for percentage is `p`. See documentation in here : http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/globalization/numberformatting.

So you should use:

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m => m)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
    .Format("p")
)
```

Standard numeric formats:

- n for number

  > kendo.culture("en-US"); kendo.toString(1234.567, "n"); //1,234.57
  >   kendo.toString(10.12, "n5"); //10.12000 kendo.toString(10.12, "n0"); //10
  >   kendo.culture("de-DE"); kendo.toString(1234.567, "n3"); //1.234,567
- c for currency

  > kendo.culture("en-US"); kendo.toString(1234.567, "c"); //$1,234.57
  >   kendo.culture("en-US"); kendo.toString(1234.567, "c0"); //$1,235
  >   kendo.culture("de-DE"); kendo.toString(1234.567, "c3"); //1.234,567 €
- p for percentage (number is multiplied by 100)

  > kendo.culture("en-US"); kendo.toString(0.222, "p"); //22.20 %
  >   kendo.culture("en-US"); kendo.toString(0.222, "p0"); //22 %
  >   kendo.culture("de-DE"); kendo.toString(0.22, "p3"); //22.000 %
- e for exponential

  > kendo.toString(0.122, "e"); //1.22e-1 kendo.toString(0.122, "e4"); //1.2200e-1

Comment: That just populates the Column with an actual p as the value. Kendo frustrate the hell out of me.

Answer (score 0):

For grid you can use this:

```
columns.Bound(e => e.Percent).ClientTemplate("#=Percent# %")
```